# Run time error '424' Object Required in Selenium VBA for Edge Browser

Tags: vba, selenium

On executing below code, system throws error

> Run Time Error '424'
>
> Object Required

Through the code, I am extracting data from a website (using Edge browser).

If match is found, a link appears on the portal from which data can be downloaded whose Xpath is `"//*[@id='downloadReport']/div"`

If link is present, the link should be clicked using code

```
Obj.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='downloadReport']/div").Click
```

Else if no match is found, the above code should be skipped as Xpath as above is not available and another macro execution should be called using

```
Call EdgeAutoTest2
```

I am new to coding
Please help me in resolving this error.

```
Sub EdgeAutoTest1()
Set Obj = New selenium.EdgeDriver

Obj.SetCapability "ms:edgeOptions", "{""excludeSwitches"":[""enable-automation""]}"
Obj.Start "edge", ""
Obj.Get "https://***website*****"
Obj.Window.Maximize

Obj.FindElementByName("croreAccount").SendKeys ("Search")
Obj.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='loadSuitFiledDataSearchAction']/div[1]/div[3]/div[4]/img").Click
    Obj.FindElementById("borrowerName").SendKeys (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C5").Value)
    Obj.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='search-button']/ul/li[1]/div/input").Click
    Obj.Wait 20000
Obj.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='three-icons']/ul/li[3]/a/div").Click
Obj.Wait 20000

If Obj.IsElementPresent(By.XPath("//*[@id='downloadReport']/div")) = True Then **'error occurs here*****
      Obj.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='downloadReport']/div").Click
      Else
      Obj.Wait 100
End If
Call EdgeAutoTest2
End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot `Click` on the element if it is not found. Either separate the line in two steps and check the existence of the element, or implement error management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue in your code is you are missing is that you didn't define *`By`*.

As you are using:

```
If Obj.IsElementPresent(By.XPath("//*[@id='downloadReport']/div")) = True Then
```

You need to:

```
Dim By As New Selenium.By
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Issue is resolved. I further request to help on below mentioned 2 issues                                                                                                                                        How to check the visibility of the element in VBA of XPath("//*[@id='downloadReport']/div")                                                                             Is there any alternative to Obj.Wait as at times due to load on server, page is not loaded completely and code Obj.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='three-icons']/ul/li[3]/a/div").Click is executed